# How does int main() and void main() work?

Tags: c, void

I am a beginner in the C language. Can anyone explain in detail using example how main(), int main(), void main(), main(void), void main(void), int main(void) work in C language?

As in, what is happening when we use void main() and what is happening when I use int main() in simple language and so on?

I know, but I can’t understand what is it doing:

1. main() - function has no arguments
2. int main() - function returns int value
3. void main() - function returns nothing, etc.

When I write a simple *[Hello, World!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%22Hello,_World!%22_program)* program using the int main() return 0, it still gives me the same output as when using void main()), so how does it work? What is its application?

Comment: `void main()` is useful mainly as an indication that you're using a textbook written by someone who doesn't know the C language very well. Of the forms you listed, only `int main(void)` is valid. (It's not *quite* that simple, but that's close enough for now.)

Answer (score 28):

Neither `main()` or `void main()` are standard C.  The former is allowed as it has an implicit `int` return value, making it the same as `int main()`.  The purpose of `main`'s return value is to return an [exit status](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status) to the operating system.

In standard C, the only valid signatures for `main` are:

```
int main(void)
```

and

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
```

The form you're using: `int main()` is an old style declaration that indicates `main` takes an unspecified number of arguments.  Don't use it - choose one of those above.

Comment: In resume, they are just allowed for compatibility backwards with old C code written when operating system didn't required an exit status. You always should to return an integer value in `main`

Comment: @Jack: `void main()` is not for backwards compatibility with anything. The same standard that first introduced the `void` keyword defined the return type of `main` as `int`.

Comment: int main(int argc, const char **argv, const char **env)

Comment: @dns, not in standard C.  The implementation can define whatever it likes, though.

Answer (score 16):

If you really want to understand ANSI C 89, I need to correct you in one thing;
In ANSI C 89 the difference between the following functions:

```
int main()
int main(void)
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
```

is:

`int main()`

- a function that expects unknown number of arguments of unknown types. Returns an integer representing the application software status.

`int main(void)`

- a function that expects no arguments. Returns an integer representing the application software status.

`int main(int argc, char * argv[])`

- a function that expects argc number of arguments and argv[] arguments. Returns an integer representing the application software status.

About when using each of the functions

> int main(void)

- you need to use this function when your program needs no initial parameters to run/ load (parameters received from the OS - out of the program it self).

> int main(int argc, char * argv[])

- you need to use this function when your program needs initial parameters to load (parameters received from the OS - out of the program it self).

About `void main()`

In ANSI C 89, when using `void main` and compiling the project AS `-ansi -pedantic` (in Ubuntu, e.g)
you will receive a warning indicating that your main function is of type void and not of type int, but you will be able to run the project.
Most C developers tend to use `int main()` on all of its variants, though `void main()` will also compile.