# Is it compulsory to use int main() in C language?

Tags: c

I just wanted to ask that-is it compulsory to use `int main()` in C language or can we use `void main()` also ? And ,is this condition is compulsory in C++ only ?

Comment: Additionally, C++ basically has the same rules for main() as C does.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how does int main() and void main() work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18928279/how-does-int-main-and-void-main-work)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is best practice to use `int main(void)` or `int main (int argc, char **argv)` because C standard says it here:

#### C11: 5.1.2.2.1 Program startup:

> 1 The function called at program startup is named `main`. The implementation declares no
>   prototype for this function. It shall be defined with a return type of `int` and with no
>   parameters:
>
> ```
> int main(void) { /* ... */ }
> ```
>
> or with two parameters (referred to here as `argc` and `argv`, though any names may be
>   used, as they are local to the function in which they are declared):
>
> ```
> int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }
> ```
>
> or equivalent;<sup>10)</sup> or in some other implementation-defined manner.

Other forms can also be used if implementation allows them, but better to stick with the standard form.

Comment: "or in some other implementation-defined manner" - does it allow some other `main` definitions?

Comment: @WojtekSurowka: Objective-C (a super-set of C, so in theory it should be 100% C compatible) tends to use `int main (int argc, const char *argv[])`. Though not _really_ that different, the use of `const`, and it not being in the standard is a significant difference, though. in C, `argv` is definitely **not** const

Comment: Unix allows ``int main( int argc, char *argv[], char *env[] )``, where env are your environment variables.  Env is null terminated, allowing for use such as ``while ( *env++ )``

Answer (score 0):

There are two allowed main signatures as of c99 which all implementations must support:

```
int main(void);
int main(int argc, char* argv[]);
```

However, implementations may support any other signatures they wish, these include some adding a third argument for passed in system info or alternative return types. To find out if any exist on your system please see the compiler documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Not just `int main()` but one can skip writing `main()` entirely.

`main()` is the entry point of a c program, this is a universal fact but actually when we dive deep, it becomes clear, that `main()` is called by another function called `_start()` which is actually the very first function called at the abstract level.

```
#include <stdio.h>
extern void _exit(register int);

int _start(){

printf(“Hello World\n”);

_exit(0);

}
```