# Code that check if the Sequence Monotone Increasing

Tags: c, loops

I need to input a number (user enters `-1` to exit) and the program needs to tell if it increasing monotone sequence.

I did it in `do-while` loop, I know that if I want to check if it is  increasing I need to check the previous number and then compare the `previous` and the `current` number.

But still, its hard to me to imagine the process of the loop.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()

{

    int num, i = 0, numPrev = 0;
    printf("Enter a number:");

    do {

        scanf("%d", &num);

        numPrev = num;
        i++;

        if (num > numPrev) 

    } while (num != -1);

        printf("The Serias is Monotinic Acsending\n");

}
```

Comment: Does it compile at all?

Comment: Yes ..you are thinking correctly by comparing the previous and current number . One way could be to raise a flag if `previous>current`. After input , check the status of the flag

Comment: [how does int main() and void main() work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18928279/how-does-int-main-and-void-main-work)

Comment: If the number is *not* monotonically ascending at any interval, you can print and exit the loop right away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make the following changes. I have added comments where required. Assuming that you wish to read the entire input!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)//refer the link given below

{

    int  i = 0, numCurr, numPrev = 0; //for storing current no. and previous no.
    int flag = 0;
    printf("Enter input:");

    do {

        scanf("%d", &numCurr);

        if(i != 0 && numCurr != -1 && numPrev > numCurr)//so that comparison begins from the second element
            flag = 1;

        numPrev = numCurr;
        i++;

    } while (numCurr != -1);

    if(flag == 0)printf("The Serias is Monotinic Acsending\n");
    else    printf("The Serias is not Monotinic Acsending\n");  

    return 0;
 }
```

Also do hve a look :[What should main() return in C and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, But I didn't understand the flag=1;  can explain, please.

Comment: @AndrewM We need to somehow store the info whether in the series any previous element is greater than current. Hence we initialize `flag=0` . While taking the input if we come across elements such that `previous>current` we change the value of `flag` to 1. So in the end if we still have `flag` equals to zero it implies the list is monotnically increasing. Do tell if anything is still unclear.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I try to compile it initializing the Flag=0 (because maybe you forgot to initialize it?) and it won't runs as I want to it to run.  the sequence is always increasing.

Comment: @AndrewM yes..my bad. I have edited the answer. And it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Key points:

- Validate user input (check `scanf` return value)
- Comparison of numbers only makes sense after the second number was inputted by the user
- Compare previous to current number before re-assigning previous

Consider the following code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int num, i = 0, numPrev = 0;
    printf("Enter a number:");

    if (!scanf("%d", &numPrev)) return -1;

    while (numPrev != -1)
    {
        if (!scanf("%d", &num)) return -1;

        if (num != -1 && num <= numPrev)
        {
            printf("The Serias is not Monotinic Acsending\n");
            return 0;
        }
        numPrev = num;
    }

    printf("The Serias is Monotinic Acsending\n");

    return 0;
}
```

If you can't return directly when a not-monotone series was found, you may need some sort of result variable to decide whether the loop was canceled (not monotone) or completed (monotone).