# Which one is correct Return value type?

Tags: c, c99

I am wroting two program that calculates a factorial. The `program #1` is to have the return value type to be void, and the `program #2` is to have the return value type to be int.

But I lack knowledge, so I don't know which one is right.

Which one is correct?

`program #1` - return value type: void

```
#include <stdio.h>

void calculateFactorial(int count, int *sum);

int main()
{
    int number;
    int sum = 1;
    
    printf("factorial number: ");
    scanf(" %d", &number);
    
    calculateFactorial(number, &sum);
    
    printf("result: %d\n", sum);
    
    return 0;
}

void calculateFactorial(int count, int *sum)
{
    if (count == 0)
    {
        return;
    }
    
    *sum *= count;

    calculateFactorial(--count, sum);
}
```

`program #2` - return value type: int

```
#include <stdio.h>

int calculateFactorial(int count, int *sum);

int main()
{
    int number;
    int sum = 1;
    
    printf("factorial number: ");
    scanf(" %d", &number);
    
    calculateFactorial(number, &sum);
    
    printf("result: %d\n", sum);
    
    return 0;
}

int calculateFactorial(int count, int *sum)
{
    if (count == 0)
    {
        return *sum;
    }
    
    *sum *= count;

    calculateFactorial(--count, sum);
}
```

Comment: The second one is wrong, since you don't return any value, the function must have void return type. Your compiler must have issued some warning.

Comment: @anastaciu Thank you. I have one question, isn't this a recursive function? So, to escape the recursive function, I tried to return it by creating a separate conditional statement without returning at the end of the function.
Even so, is it determined that there is no return value?

Comment: 첫 번째는 꼬리 재귀 함수이고, 두 번째는 일반적인 재귀 함수이다. 재귀 함수는 가독성을 높여주지만, 스택에 데이터를 쌓기 때문에 스택오버플로우가 발생할 수도 있음을 유의해야 한다. 꼬래 재귀 함수란, 재귀 함수의 가독성은 그대로 유지하되 단점을 보완한 재귀 함수이다. 이때, 컴파일러가 꼬리 재귀 최적화 기능을 제공해야만 하며, 그렇지 않다면 둘 다 별로이다.

Comment: it is a recursive function, if you added a conditional statement at the end, chances are that not all paths return a value. Recursive functions can have `void` return type, you still have the stop condition, and the missing return will be automatically done by the function, it's the best option IMO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one is correct, and the second one is wrong. In the second one, you don't return anything even though the function type is int. You are supposed to return an int. E.g.,

```
int func() {//Whatever code}
```

is wrong. It needs to return an `int`. The correct version is:

```
int func() {
     return 0; //Or whatever int
}
```

If you don't want to return anything, then you need to have type void.

```
void func() {
    return 0;
}
```

This is wrong. You can't return anything, and you need to do:

```
void func {
    return; //Not having a return won't do anything though, you can leave it blank
}

void func {} //Works, no need to return
```

You may be confused because:

```
1. void main() {} //Works and
2. int main() {} //Works as well, and
3. int main() {return 0;} //Works as well
```

So, no 1. is absolute rubbish. It works somehow, but it's wrong and it's rubbish. Check *[How does int main() and void main() work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18928279/how-does-int-main-and-void-main-work)*.

In no. 2 the compiler adds `return 0` for you. It only happens in main function.

No. 3 is perfectly correct.

Answer (score 0):

There is no right or wrong when it comes to how you handle returning values from a function: they can be returned as a direct value, or as a secondary value through a passed pointer. There is, however, one (or more) right way(s) to DO each, and many wrong ways. In your two examples, the first one is done a right way, and the second one is done a wrong way. In the second example, there is no return for the case where count != 0, so it is a wrong way.

I general, I prefer a simple mathematical function (like factorial) to return a direct value (in this case, as an int); to do so I would write the `calculateFactorial` function like this:

```
int calculateFactorial(int num)
{
    if (num <= 1) return 1;
    return num * calculateFactorial(num - 1);
}
```

`sum` is not needed in this scenario, just print the returned value (which is technically a product, not a sum anyway).