# Inserting Int Pointer in List (C)

Tags: c, linked-list

I am very new and need some help with this code for college homework.
I am trying to write the code for inserting a Node to the end of the list in C but something with creating the new node isn't working.

First, here is the code I received in the assignment:

```
typedef struct listNode {
    int* dataPtr;
    struct listNode* next;
}ListNode;

typedef struct list
{
    ListNode* head;
    ListNode* tail;
}List;
```

And:

```
List getList()
{
    List res;
    int size, num, i;
    makeEmptyList(&res);
    printf("Please enter the number of items to be entered:\n");
    scanf("%d", &size);
    printf("Please enter the numbers:\n");
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &num);
        insertDataToEndList(&res, num);
    }
    return res;
}

void main()
{
    List lst1, lst2, mergedList;
    lst1 = getList();
    lst2 = getList();
    mergedList = merge(lst1,lst2);
    printf("Merged list:\n");
    printList(&mergedList);

    freeList(&lst1);
    freeList(&lst2);
    freeList(&mergedList);
}
```

And here is my attempt at writing the code for `insertDataToEndList`:

```
// Add Node to end list

void insertDataToEndList(List* lst, int data)
{
    ListNode* newTail;
    newTail = createNewListNode(&data, NULL);
    insertNodeToEndList(lst, newTail);
}
ListNode* createNewListNode(int* data, ListNode* next)
{
    ListNode* res;
    res = (ListNode*)malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
    res->dataPtr = data;
    res->next = next;
    return res;
}

void insertNodeToEndList(List* lst, ListNode* tail)
{
    if (isEmptyList(lst) == true)
        lst->head = lst->tail = tail;
    else
    {
        lst->tail->next = tail;
        lst->tail = tail;
    }
    tail->next = NULL;
}
```

The problem is that when I print the two lists that have been input, the printed values are not at all what I had input.

Comment: "something with creating the new node isn't working" what isn't working? What have you tried?

Comment: `lst->tail->next = NULL;` if it is the tail then there is nothing after it

Comment: In programming, there is no such thing as "something isn't working".  There is a very specific sequence of steps that you take, which results in a very specific error, with a very specific error message.  Come on, don't keep them a secret.

Comment: `createNewListNode(&data, NULL);` will lead to undefined behaviour: `data` is a local variable, and after `insertDataToEndList` returns, it is no longer allocated. Yet its address is now used in a node...

Comment: BTW, can you explain why you need a node to have a *pointer* to (apparently one) `int`? Why not that int itself?

Comment: Tip: Using `== true` will bite you one day. Leave that out. `if` already checks if it's true.

Comment: There's lots of bugs here that will surface if compiling and paying attention to warnings. Start with fixing those.

Comment: @trincot I have to have int as a pointer in the ListNode because that's what was asked of us in the homework exercise. I'm not allowed to change that part.

Comment: @trincot How am I supposed to do this then? In the full program I get two already made lists and I'm supposed to sort them by making a new list with copies of the Nodes of the other two lists (that is specifically how they asked us to do it)

Comment: This is information that is not in the question. What about the integers that `dataPtr` point to: they can be reused by the copy, or they need to be copied too? How to you call `insertDataToEndList`?

Comment: @trincot the integers that dataPtr point to can be reused, insertDataToEndList() is called in two places: the function List getList() that was provided by the course and the function List merge(List lst1, List lst2) that I need to write myself. (here is a link to the main+ getlist() function: https://pastes.io/mc2e7mlpuo). thank you so much for your patience

Comment: Was `insertDataToEndList` also provided, or did you write it yourself? What else was provided? The `struct` definitions? It is not clear to me what exactly was provided and what you need to write. You say `getList` was provided, but it calls `insertDataToEndList`... I'm puzzled.

Comment: @trincot only this and the struct definitions were the only things provided. getList calls insertDataToEndList because they want us to "fill in the blanks".

Comment: Alright. What exactly is the blank? Did you get the statement `insertDataToEndList(&res, num);` that we see in `getList`, or is that a line you wrote yourself? You know, it would really save us a lot of time, if you would just quote the assigment literally in your question.

Comment: @trincot I would have loved to do that from the beginning if the assignment was written in English. I can attempt to translate it for you into English as best as I can: [assaigment](https://pastes.io/mgj5z2wcgx)

Comment: That link has the following: *"You will need to write the functions Void freeList(&lst1)"*, but that is not a valid function header. What is `&lst1`?

Comment: It was my mistake when translating, copied it wrong. I meant to write Void freeList(List* lst1), same with Void makeEmptyList(List* res)

Comment: I like this sentinel structure approach to linked lists, but I assume that this won't been passed though a tool like Valgrind, because this is just a memory-leak [at best] waiting to happen: storing a pointer leads to confusion over who owns and is responsible for the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `data` parameter of the `insertDataToEndList` function is allocated on the stack, its address is no longer referencing allocated memory once that function returns. Yet you've saved this address in `res->dataPtr = data;`. This will lead to undefined behaviour when you'll read the memory pointed to by that `dataPtr` (e.g. when later you print that list or do the merge).

So don't use `&data`. Instead pass `data` to `insertDataToEndList` with this call:

```
    newTail = createNewListNode(data, NULL);
```

And then change `insertDataToEndList` to fix this bug:

```
ListNode* createNewListNode(int data, ListNode* next) // First param is int
{
    ListNode* res = malloc(sizeof(*res));
    res->dataPtr = malloc(sizeof(int)); // Allocate the memory for the int
    (*res->dataPtr) = data; // Copy the int
    res->next = next;
    return res;
}
```

Some other remarks:

- [Don't cast what `malloc` returns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/5459839)
- Don't compare the result of `isEmpty(lst)` with `true`. Just do:

  ```
      if (isEmptyList(lst))
  ```
- Make sure you declare functions before you call them. So unless you had already declared the functions, you should move the `insertDataToEndList` function definition below the other two functions it depends on.

The code you received shows several bad practices, and makes one doubt about the quality of the course material you are looking at. For instance:

- [`void main()` is wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18928279/5459839), and like a comment says, it's *"...an indication that you're using a textbook written by someone who doesn't know the C language very well."*.
- The `freeList` function takes `List*` argument, which suggests that the memory allocated for the list (not only its nodes) should be freed, yet this makes no sense, since the `main` function has declared them as `List` variables, so `free` should not be called on the list itself. It would be more consistent if the involved lists would all be allocated on the heap.
- Storing `int` values in dynamically allocated memory for one int, is useless and a bad decision.

Comment: Thank you for your patience and your help! I will also keep in mind everything you mentioned about the code provided by the course and the other remarks.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't going to work, since `data` will be a local copy of `data` on the stack:

```
void insertDataToEndList(List* lst, int data)
{
    ListNode* newTail;
    newTail = createNewListNode(&data, NULL);
    insertNodeToEndList(lst, newTail);
}
```

It needs to be similar to createNewListNode:

```
void insertDataToEndList(List* lst, int *data)
{
    ListNode* newTail;
    newTail = createNewListNode(data, NULL);
    insertNodeToEndList(lst, newTail);
}
```

The question doesn't specify where the data is located that the list nodes are pointing to with `dataPtr`.